# How to update the NextAuth session object client-side with RTK query?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I have next-auth set up in my application and I am using reduxjs toolkit with RTK query for API calls. There is a refresh token route set up on the backend to refresh jwt tokens.

I am trying to update the session.jwt property from the RTK base query method, but the session object from getSession is read-only, so I can not directly update the jwt token from the base query. There is a useSession hook that provides an update method, but that will not work because I can not use hooks in the base query.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:1337/",
  prepareHeaders: async (headers) => {
    const session = await getSession();
    if (session) {
      headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${session.jwt}`);
      return headers;
    }
  },
});

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args: any, api: any, extraOptions: any) => {
  const session = await getSession();
  let result: any = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
  if (
    result.error &&
    (result.error.status === 401 || result.error.status === 403)
  ) {
    const data = await baseQuery(
      {
        url: "token/refresh",
        method: "POST",
        body: { refreshToken: session?.refreshToken },
      },
      api,
      extraOptions
    );
    if (data) {
      //Trying to update the session property to take the new jwt but does not work.
      session.jwt = data.jwt;
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  tagTypes: ["Orders"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getOrders: builder.query({
      query: () => {
        return {
          url: "api/orders?populate[products][populate][0]=*",
        };
      },
      providesTags: ["Orders"],
    }),
  }),
});
```

I tried to directly update the session.jwt property with the new jwt received from the token/refresh endpoint, but that does not work, as the session object is read-only.

I am trying to only have the refresh token logic inside of the base query method, rather than use the update method from the useSession hook in a component.

Comment: Are you getting the session>token from getSession() with this approach?? Is it working properly?

Comment: Yes, I am receiving the session token with getSession() and I can read that value like I have stated in the post; "the session object from getSession is read-only." The issue is that I can not update the session.jwt property without using the update method from the useSession( ) hook in a component, but I would like to update it from a client-side baseQuery() function with RTK-query instead of updating from a component, because that saves me from having to put that hook in every component I need to use re-auth with. Sorry but I am not sure what you are referring to by "Is it working properly?"

Comment: When I try to use the useSession() hook inside the prepareHeaders, I'm getting an error cannot call react hook inside a function. So I got stuck with passing headers from next-auth to RTK query.]

Comment: That is because useSession is a hook, hooks can only be used in React components, I am using the getSession method inside the prepareHeaders method for the baseQuery: `import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"`. This is a client-side function, not a React component. Switch your usage of useSession() with getSession()

Comment: Thanks, I've been wrapping my head around for far too long. I didn't look at the getSession method. This was the right way.